# How to apply style to HTML subdocuments?

Tags: html, css, nested, external

I tend to apply my own custom CSS documents to certain sites, since I prefer dark backgrounds with light text as opposed to the vice-versa standard, and very few sites have a "dark mode" or otherwise cater to that preference, this site itself being an excellent example.

However, I was recently stricken by something odd - an entire HTML document nested inside of another one. (I now understand this is achieved via use of an `<iframe>` and so it's nearly impossible to style without JS or something) I can only apply the custom stylesheet to the parent document, though.

So, long story short, I'm wondering what sort of selectors I would have to use to target elements of the nested document only - for example, selecting the `<body>` of the nested document. Would I refer to a `body` in a `html` in a `!DOCTYPE` *that is also in* a `body`? What about recursively nested documents?

Whether this nesting thing is poor practice or not does not immediately concern me -- there seems to be a valid use case for it and, regardless, I'm not building the site. What I DO care about is how to add styles to it externally.

Comment: It sounds like <iframe>, you can't apply any style to it with css only if it's from another domain.

Comment: That is possible with JS. If you use `document.getElementById(...)` to get the iframe, you can access the inner document with the `contentDocument` property.

Comment: @Pangloss Yeah, like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you literally have a document that has been 'injected' into another document, you would simply target it with the expected identifiers:

To target elements **unique** to the sub-document:

```
body body [element] {
}
```

To target elements that exist within **both** documents, you would just use the standard:

```
[element] {
}
```

The above would apply the style to any desired element that is contained within either document.

Please be aware that you **cannot** style an iframe inside a document with CSS -- you'd either have to find a way to manipulate the iframe's CSS itself, or use JavaScript to target the desired elements with `document.getElementById()`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: CSS **never** applies to elements inside an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose the `<iframe>` bit was an important inclusion. Apologies, I'm obviously not used to dealing with... these.